# XMLHttpRequest causing strange bug in JavaScript title game

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a tile game in JS and am loading a text based map with a XMLHttpRequest object. All works well until I actually try to draw the background. The map gets initialized, but it doesn't seem to be "fully" initialized by the time I try to loop through the rows. When I try to call `map[rowNum].length` I get an undefined error. In the debugger, I can see that once the code jumping back to `loadMapHttp()` which is where the XMLHttpRequest object is defined. I don't understand why it's doing this.

```
var map =[];
var tiles =[];
var background = new Image();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var graphicsContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

background.src = "imgs/tileSheet.jpg";

function loadMapHttp() {
    var conn = new XMLHttpRequest();
    conn.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;

    conn.open("GET","map.txt",true);
    conn.send();


    function handleStateChange() {
        if(conn.readyState === 4){
            loadMap2(conn.status == 200 ? conn.responseText : null);
        }
    }

}


function loadMap2(text) {

    if(text == null){
        console.warn("Http Error");
        return;
    }

    console.log("text received was: " + text);

    var testMap = text;
    var rows = testMap.split("\n");
    for(var rowNum =0; rowNum < rows.length; rowNum++){
        rows[rowNum] = rows[rowNum].trim();
        map.push([]);
        var cols = rows[rowNum].split("");
        console.log(cols);
        for(var colNum = 0; colNum<cols.length; colNum++){
            map[rowNum][colNum] = cols[colNum];
        }
    }
}

function prepTiles() {
    var TILESET_LEFT = 0;
    var TILESET_TOP = 0;
    var TILE_WIDTH = 31.2;
    var TILE_HEIGHT = 31.2;
    var tileCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var tileContext = tileCanvas.getContext('2d');

    //BRICK
    tileContext.drawImage(background, TILESET_TOP+TILE_WIDTH*2, TILESET_TOP, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, 0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
    tiles.push(tileContext.getImageData(0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT));

    //DIRT
    tileContext.drawImage(background, TILESET_LEFT+TILE_WIDTH*17, TILESET_TOP+TILE_HEIGHT*6, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, 0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
    tiles.push(tileContext.getImageData(0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT));

    //GRASS
    tileContext.drawImage(background, TILESET_LEFT+TILE_WIDTH*6, TILESET_TOP+TILE_HEIGHT*12, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, 0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
    tiles.push(tileContext.getImageData(0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT));

}

function getTile(char) {

    if(char == 'B'){
        return tiles[0];
    }
    if(char == 'D'){
        return tiles[1];
    }
    if(char == 'G'){
        return tiles[2];
    }
}

function drawBackground(){

    for(var rowNum=0; rowNum < 6; rowNum++){

        console.log(map[rowNum]);
        for(var colNum=0; colNum < map[rowNum].length; colNum++){
            var tile = getTile(map[rowNum][colNum]);
            graphicsContext.putImageData(tile, colNum*31, rowNum*31);

        }
    }
}



function startGame() {
    loadMapHttp();
    prepTiles();
    drawBackground();

}

startGame();
```

Comment: why are you actually checking colNum < map[rowNum].length?

Comment: your `drawBackground` will execute before `loadMapHttp` has had a chance to load anything - because XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I want to iterate through all the characters stored in each row @GraveyardQueen

Comment: How can I guarantee that drawBackground will execute before loadMapHttp?